# Count the number of times a string occurs in a row with the type SET

Tags: mysql, count

My database has got four columns: `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` each one has the type `SET('a','b','c','d')`.

**I want to know how many times `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` occurs in each column.**

I guess I could do something like this

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database as d WHERE d.a = 'one') AS one,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database as d WHERE d.a = 'two') AS two,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database as d WHERE d.a = 'three') AS three,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database as d WHERE d.a = 'four') AS four
FROM database
LIMIT 1
```

four times which I know would work. Or I could fetch the entire result and count what's in the array.

Can I somehow do this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select one,count(*) from db group by one
select two,count(*) from db group by two
etc
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect, but how would I go about if I wanted it to not count NULL?

Comment: You can exclude them in a where, like 'where two is not null'

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple counts in a single select using `case` and `sum`:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when d.a = 'one' then 1 else 0 end) as SumAIsOne
,   sum(case when d.b = 'two' then 1 else 0 end) as SumBIsTwo
,   <other counts here>
FROM database
```